# React TypeError: this is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Вообщем задача такая: написать компонент который будет возвращать тэг p и менять цвет при клике курсором на него.
Я написал следующий компонент:

```
class Rgb extends React.Component
{
    constructor (props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = { color: "red" };
    }
    Cklicker () 
    {
        if (this.state.color == "red") this.setState({ color: "green" });
        if (this.state.color == "green") this.setState({ color: "blue" });
        if (this.state.color == "blue") this.setState({ color: "red" });
    }
    render () {
        return (<p onClick={this.Cklicker} style={this.state}>RGB</p>);
    }
}
```

Но при нажатий вместо того что бы поменять цвет возникает ошибка:

**TypeError: this is undefined
Cklicker**

```
  133 | }
  134 | Cklicker () 
  135 | {
> 136 |     if (this.state.color == "red") this.setState({ color: "green" });
  137 | ^   if (this.state.color == "green") this.setState({ color: "blue" });
  138 |     if (this.state.color == "blue") this.setState({ color: "red" });
  139 | }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React не устанавливает контекст для обработчиков событий. Добавьте `this.Clicker = this.Clicker.bind(this)` в конструктор.

Answer (score 2):

Либо используй стрелочные функции. Они привязывают текущий контекст к функции.

```
Cklicker = () => { //код функции }
```